# SIGALRM and sleep() c++

Tags: c++

I am currently designing a small line following robot that navigates via IR beacons. It is all coded in C++ however integrating the line following and IR receiving seems to have broken it. The IR uses an interrupt service routine to look for an IR signal using an interval timer and SIGALRM. The pathfinding function, along with several of the other robot operations, use sleep(). It has now come to my attention that you cannot use SIGALRM and sleep() in the same program as the SIGALRM wakes the process up prematurely. Is there a good workaround for this besides simply ridding the whole program of sleep() functions?

Comment: The only option I could think of is ugly hackery to replace sleep() with poll() or select() of an empty file descriptor set with a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One band-aid fix is to use the `nanosleep` function instead of `sleep`. If `nanosleep` wakes up prematurely, it stores the remaining time into the time structure, so you can re-try. You can wrap this in your own function that resembles `sleep`.  Since `nanosleep` isn't ever implemented with `SIGALRM`, there is no reason why it would wake up prematurely.  Be sure to use `sigaction` to set up your alarm signal handler, and specify `SA_RESTART` in the flags, all the same. This allows your signal not to disturb restartable system calls.

Comment: Thanks, this totally solved my problem! I used a wrapper that calls nanosleep recursively until all the time has passed, and the interrupts don't seem to change the pause time.